# .NET MAUI Prism page cannot find ViewModel

Tags: c#, maui

--------  MauiProgram.cs  --------
The problem is basically I am using prism mvvm framework in my .net maui project. Here I am adding a navigationpage inside the tabbed page. In this navigation page, I have a content page called ProfilePage. Here I am matching my profilepage.xaml file with my viewmoldellocatorprovider and my profilepageviewmodel.cs file. but when I make a command call in the tapGestureRecognizer event in the profilepage.xaml file, the command is not triggered or when I use the OnAppearing() method, which is one of the prism pagelifecycle methods, it is not triggered in the page pain. I tried to do this by using the BindingContext property in the xaml file, but my viewmodel gives an error because it takes a constructor parameter. my codes are as shown above, there is no problem with the pages. The only problem at this stage is that the profilepage.xaml file cannot access the profilepageviewmodel.cs file as viewmodel. i hope i could explain

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>().ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("Anybody-Regular.ttf", "Anybody");
                fonts.AddFont("Arizonia-Regular.ttf", "Arizona");
    
            })
            .UsePrism(prism =>
            {
    
                prism.RegisterTypes(container =>
                {
    
                    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<LoginPage, LoginPageViewModel>();
                    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<RegisterPage, RegisterPageViewModel>();
                    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<BasketPage, BasketPageViewModel>();
                    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<GiftPage, GiftPageViewModel>();
                    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<HomePage, HomePageViewModel>();
                    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<FoodMenuPage, FoodMenuPageViewModel>();
                    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<DrinkMenuPage, DrinkMenuPageViewModel>();
                    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ProfilePage, ProfilePageViewModel>();
                    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<HomeNavigationPage, HomeNavigationPageViewModel>();
                    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<MenuPage, MenuPageViewModel>();
                    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<PaymentPage, PaymentPageViewModel>();
    
    
    
    
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage, LoginPageViewModel>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<RegisterPage, RegisterPageViewModel>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<BasketPage, BasketPageViewModel>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<GiftPage, GiftPageViewModel>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<HomePage, HomePageViewModel>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<FoodMenuPage, FoodMenuPageViewModel>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<DrinkMenuPage, DrinkMenuPageViewModel>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<ProfilePage, ProfilePageViewModel>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<HomeNavigationPage, HomeNavigationPageViewModel>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<MenuPage, MenuPageViewModel>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<PaymentPage, PaymentPageViewModel>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<ProductsPage>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<EditProfilePage>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<MyAddressPage>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<HelpPage>();
                    container.RegisterForNavigation<MyOrdersPage>();
    
    
    
                }).OnAppStart(nameof(LoginPage));
            });
    
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
    
    
        return builder.Build();
    }

}
```

------  ProfilePageViewModel  -------

I have a method called LogoutCommand on this page, when the user clicks on the layout, I want to return to the login page

```
namespace VoilaMobileApp.Src.ViewModels.ProfileVM
{
public class ProfilePageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
public INavigationService navService { get; set; }

        public ProfilePageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
        }
      
    
        public ICommand LogoutCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(LoginPage));
                });
            }
        }
    
    }

}
```

------  HomeNavigationPage  ---------

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="VoilaMobileApp.Src.Views.HomeNavigation.HomeNavigationPage"
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
xmlns:hmPg="clr-namespace:VoilaMobileApp.Src.Views.HomeViews"
xmlns:mnPg="clr-namespace:VoilaMobileApp.Src.Views.MenuViews"
xmlns:bsPg="clr-namespace:VoilaMobileApp.Src.Views.BasketViews"
xmlns:prfPg="clr-namespace:VoilaMobileApp.Src.Views.ProfileViews"
xmlns:profvm="clr-namespace:VoilaMobileApp.Src.ViewModels.ProfileVM"
android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
BarBackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource CustomPurple}"
SelectedItem="White"
UnselectedTabColor="White"
x:Name="HomeNav"
>

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage  BarTextColor="White" BarBackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource CustomPurple}" Title="Hesabım" IconImageSource="profile_menu_icon.svg">
    
            <x:Arguments>
    
                <prfPg:ProfilePage>
    
                    <NavigationPage.TitleView >
                        <Grid   BackgroundColor="Transparent" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0,0,20,0" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="60" ></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
                            <Label  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="HESABIM"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" ></Label>
    
                        </Grid>
    
                    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    
                </prfPg:ProfilePage>
    
            </x:Arguments>
    
        </NavigationPage>
    
    </TabbedPage.Children>

</TabbedPage>
```

--------- ProilePage.Xaml ---------

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="VoilaMobileApp.Src.Views.ProfileViews.ProfilePage"
xmlns:vm = "clr-namespace:VoilaMobileApp.Src.ViewModels.ProfileVM"
x:Name="ProfileView">

    <ContentPage.Content>
    
    
    
                <Grid Margin="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
    
    
    
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <StackLayout Margin="0,0,20,0"  HeightRequest="50" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>

                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                        <Grid HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Source="logout_icon.svg" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"></Image>
                            <Label TextColor="Red" Margin="20,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16"  Text="Çıkış Yap" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"  ></Label>
                            <Image  Source="right_arrow_icon.svg"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ></Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
    
    
    
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

I would appreciate if you help me with my codes as above. have a nice day.

Comment: "but xaml file doesn't see it" - this is not a very helpful description of the problem.  Please provide the exact error message or describe the specific problem in detail

Comment: Do your `xaml` files actually have those "\"? Also you probably have better chance at getting an answer if you can give us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of all that huge code.

Comment: Have you registered the navigation service? You should have something like `mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, MauiNavigationService>();` so the `ProfilePageViewModel` can get the dependency for its constructor.

Comment: the problem is not INavigationService , the problem is ProfilePage.xaml file does not recognize ProfilePageViewModel.cs as viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

In Prism MAUI, use `container.RegisterForNavigation<ViewA, ViewAViewModel>();` instead of using the static ViewModelLocationProvider.

Then you can also use "ViewModel First Navigation":

```
NavigationService.CreateBuilder()
    .AddSegement<ViewAViewModel>()
    .NavigateAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem ViewModelLocatorProvider is not working, instead I used the class named ViewModelLocatorProvider2 my problem is solved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).